# PHP Error output - Plesk 9.2 with IIS7 and FastCGI

Tags: php, iis-7, error-handling, fastcgi, plesk

Where can I view PHP errors that are generated by a Plesk 9.2 website?

I currently get a generic 500 error when I create a test PHP error:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I have, unsuccessfully, tried to activate error reporting in the Plesk global php.ini file:

```
...\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.ini
display_errors = On
```

To the best of my knowledge Plesk 9.2 uses IIS7 and FastCGI.

Any Plesk wizards out there, that know the recommended way of debugging PHP errors on a Plesk website?

Thanks!

Comment: I suddenly started getting some PHP errors. They are only plain text errors though.

Comment: When I set fastcgi.logging = 0 it DOES disable any php error output. Changing display_errors doesn't seem to have any affect.

Comment: that's not a true error message. Use Firefox to view the page or turn off IE's friendly error message option.

Comment: This is in Firefox. Thanks though.

Comment: I didn't know serverfault existed. Sorry. -1 though?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. you have to ask the admin to give you access.  In my case the best he was going to do was to give me a read only symbolic link to it.  And he added this line to  .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```